# Slow I/O on VM hosts

Tags: io, centos, vmware, system-administration, iscsi

I am currently debugging guests of a host of mine that is suffering from high latency but acceptable read/write speeds on CentOS 6. This VM is connected to a VM host which has its storage on a SAN that I am reading/writing to. 7K/10K RPM HDDs.

Here is a test output (CentOS - LSI Logic SAS):

```
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 10.4863 s, 102 MB/s
```

Here is another test output (Windows - same SAN, different volume, VMWare Paravirtual, updated tools):

```
Read IO 9MiB/s, 1152 I/O per s, 582ms latency on last I/O request
```

Here is yet another test ouput from a machine with direct access to SAN:

```
Read IO 90MiB/s, 11575 I/O per s, 667ms latency on last I/O request
```

Am I facing a throttle or bottleneck through VMWare or are there a bigger issue? How do I go about solving this issue as I am getting acceptable speeds on the CentOS machine and Windows machine with direct access to the SAN.

Comment: Probably worth diving into ESXTOP on your ESXi host and looking into some of the latency values to try and determine the bottleneck. The following blog has some examples towards the middle around storage performance troubleshooting: https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2018/08/vmware-vsphere-esxi-storage-performance-troubleshooting/

Comment: @KyleRuddy Thanks for the information. I used the esxtop command to determine the cause but I expected to see a different result of kernel latency or something but I ended up seeing guest latency spiking. Does this mean it is a guest issue and not a host issue --> SAN issue?